# Can only get CSS dropdown to appear on hover

Tags: css, drop-down-menu, hover

I would like to change my current menu to allow for one dropdown: Products.  My test page can be found [here](http://yipcabbage.com/00) This is my HTML:

```
<nav>
       <ul class="menu">
        <li class="current"><a href="">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="">About Us</a></li>
        <li class="subNav"><a class="selected">Products</a>
        <ul>
    <li><a href="">Designer Bags</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="">Cowhides</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="">Hand-carved Geese</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="">Antler Chandeliers</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
         <li><a href="">Gallery</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Shows</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Contact</a></li>
        <li><a href="" target="_blank">Shop</a></li>
      </ul>
   </nav>
```

My original CSS:

```
.nav-buttons{text-align:center;padding-bottom:17px;}
#nav{overflow:hidden;display:inline-block}
#nav li{float:left;overflow:hidden;margin:0 10px}
#nav li a{display:block;background:url(../images/pags.png) no-repeat 0 0;
width:19px;height:19px;
line-height:0;font-size:0;
}
#nav li a:hover,#nav li.showPage a{background-position: 0 bottom}

nav{float:right;padding:12px 0 0 0}
.menu {
font-size:0;
line-height:0;
padding:0;
z-index:99;
position:relative;
margin-right:21px;
}

.menu > li {
 position:relative;
 float:left;    
 margin-left:11px;
 border-radius:5px;
-moz-border-radius:5px;
-webkit-border-radius:5px;
 background:url(../images/point.png)
 }

.menu li  a{
 color:#b3adad;
 font-size:18px;
 line-height:20px;
 display:block;    
 position:relative;
 text-decoration:none !important;   
 padding:7px 12px 9px;
 font-family: 'Noto Sans', sans-serif;
 }


.menu li.current,
.menu li:hover {
 background:#9c6f51;
 }

.menu li.current a,
.menu li:hover a{
 color:#fff
 }
```

And this bit of CSS I just added today:

```
nav a {
font-weight: 800;
padding: 5px 10px;
display: block;
}

nav > ul > li.subNav ul {
display: none;
position: absolute;
top: 100%;
left: 0;
white-space: nowrap;
background: #fff;
}

nav ul li.subNav:hover ul {
display: block;
}
```

It seems to want to work with the exception that I see no sub-menu unless I hover over it.  I've come here for help because I'm afraid to mess with the original CSS and thus ruin my navigation throughout the rest of the site.  Is there something I can add that will cause the menu to appear within just the "subNav" class, without affecting the rest of the menu or site navigation?  (The original CSS came with this template and I do note that font-size:0 is used a few times.  Since the menu worked well before I felt I needed to add a dropdown, I have been reluctant to change that, since I would only be experimenting without understanding.)

Answer (score 0):

I've sorted it.  I had to change the background color in the "subNav" class, in order for the site menu's overall font color to show up.  It's there; I just couldn't see it.